# Un équivalent au proverbe « the chickens will come (home) to roost » ?

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, proverbes

Dans une [déclaration](https://www.aclu.org/news/aclu-comment-potential-national-emergency-declaration) de l'[*American Civil Liberties Union*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_am%C3%A9ricaine_pour_les_libert%C3%A9s_civiles) (ACLU) on trouve la phrase suivante :

> [...] **The chickens will come to roost** when the next president uses
>   these powers to call a national emergency on gun control or climate
>   change. (M. Anthony Romero, ACLU, je souligne)

Il s'agit vraisemblablement d'une variation (sans *home*) sur le thème du proverbe « [the chickens come home to roost](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_chickens_come_home_to_roost) » et Wiktionnaire explique « a person's past wrongdoings will return to negatively affect them. » [ Les méfaits passés d'une personne vont revenir l'atteindre négativement — ma traduction ]. Voir aussi [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/roost#etymonline_v_43894), la variante/l'origine avec les [malédictions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curses,_like_chickens,_come_home_to_roost#English) (*curses, like chickens, come home to roost*) voire le [grand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Chaucer) [Chaucer](https://books.google.com/books?id=fkKniUPe_QYC&lpg=PT880&dq=And%20ofte%20tyme%20swich%20cursynge%20wrongfully%20retorneth%20agayn%20to%20hym%20that%20curseth%2C%20as%20a%20bryd%20that%20retorneth%20agayn%20to%20his%20owene%20nest&pg=PT880#v=snippet&q=%22byrd%20that%20retorneth%22&f=false) (*And ofte tyme swich cursynge wrongfully retorneth agayn to hym that curseth, as a bryd that retorneth agayn to his owene nest.*) pour fins d'inspiration...

---

- Quel proverbe ou quelle expression (idiomatique) convient pour exprimer fidèlement ce dont il est question ici (en tenant compte si possible ou souhaitable de l'origine et du ton du proverbe) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions :

> - [Il en payera les pots cassés](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/payer_les_pots_cass%C3%A9s)
> - Il en subira les conséquences
> - [Il s'en mordra les doigts](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/32277)